# How to dynamically replace bb tags?

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I need an intelligent way to allow users to post voice clips from Forvo in their lessons. Forvo requires usage of the helper using $this->Forvo->word('hola', 'es').

An idea would be to allow the user to use bb-code like [forvo=hola,es], but how to implement this? The only thing I can come up with is using a lot of substr, strpos... which would require at least 35 lines of code and this would not be pretty and secure.

```
<?php
// Replace forvos in the lesson
$lesson = $lesson['Lesson']['body'];

// Todo: 
// Replace [forvo=hello,en] by javascript from
// $this->Forvo->word('hello', 'en');

// I seem unable to use regex's like this
$pattern[0] = "/\[forvo\=(.*),(.*)]";
$replace[0] = $this->Forvo->word($1, $2);
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $lesson);

?>
```

Example of a lesson would be:

```
Pronounciations in Dutch
    een [forvo=een,nl]
    en [forvo=en,nl]
    de [forvo=de,nl]
    in [forvo=in,nl]
    met [forvo=met,nl]
```

Comment: try looking at preg_replace_callback() http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Waygood. It works with preg_replace_callback.

```
<?php
// Replace forvos in the lesson
$lesson = $lesson['Lesson']['body'];

function forvize($match) {
    $word = $match[1];
    $language = $match[2];
    $link = "http://apifree.forvo.com/action/word-pronunciations/format/js-tag  /word/".$word."/language/".$language."/order/rate-desc/limit/1/key/123456789/";
    $link = file_get_contents($link);
    return $link;
}

//URL's
$lesson = preg_replace_callback("/\[forvo\=(.*),(.*)\]/", 'forvize', $lesson);
?>
```